# UK visa for less than 24 hours of stay

Tags: visas, uk

I wish to travel Europe this December with my spouse. We will be there on Schengen Visa. We want to be at London on the eve of New Year and would return to Paris on 1st January, so our stay in London (UK being outside Schengen Area) will be for less than 24 hours. Do we need a UK visa for that?

Comment: Yes it is a visit nonetheless. You aren't in transit either.

Comment: @MarkMayo if the OP is on a Schengen, that's sufficient for an answer

Comment: If you're planning to watch the New Year's Eve fireworks in central London, be aware that you need to buy [tickets in advance](http://www.timeout.com/london/things-to-do/new-years-eve-fireworks-in-london-how-to-get-tickets) and numbers are limited (because it was getting so popular that even with large numbers of police doing crowd control, the sheer volume of people was getting risky).

Answer (score 1):

You are travelling from Schengen and returning to Schengen (i.e., not a bona fide transit case) and you will need a [Standard Visitor Visa](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/449641/20150803_Immigration_Rules_-_Appendix_V.pdf) *even if your visit is to attend a single event*.

To apply both you and your wife should open an account at [Visa4UK](https://www.visa4uk.fco.gov.uk/home/welcome) and complete the application.  You will be able to apply at any British post that issues visas, so you could apply from within Schengen.  However, the application needs to have lots of evidence submitted with it, so you may find yourself in a better position to apply from home.

You [do not need to submit travel reservations or London hotel bookings](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/423699/2015_04_20_Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_Final__2__-_CLEAN.pdf) with your application.

**Adding...** If you need a recommendation for an ethical and trustworthy adviser to handle your application, you can ask another question.